Crystal Reports SP 33 Runtime ASP.NET Integrated security
I'm using Crystal reports runtime 33 in ASP.NET for the first time, last version that we used was 21. The reports connection it's with SQL Server and the code used:
Dim cnnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
With cnnInfo
.ServerName = "(local)"
.DatabaseName = "MYDB"
.IntegratedSecurity = True
End With

Call SetDBLogonForReport(cnnInfo, fCR)
Call SetDBLogonForSubReport(cnnInfo, fCR)

The problem is that Crystal Reports always tries to connect to the database using the IIS Application Pool login instead of the impersonated user. Impersonation doesn't work.
From (sp33) to (sp26). Impersonation doesn't work for report.
Impersonation does work for report with SAP Crystal Reports (sp25) and less.
Does anybody knows why? What I need to change to impersonation works?
Tested:
From (sp33) to (sp26). Impersonation doesn't work for report.
Impersonation does work for report with SAP Crystal Reports (sp25) and less.
Expected to happen:
IntegratedSecurity = True, should change the user that execute the SP at SQL SERVER.

This looks very similar to this issue. You may need to use Fiddler to get relevant information to locate the problem.
